# need to add checkboxes dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to add checkboxes dynamically with the help of javascript. However my java-script only replaces the earlier element. I need to add the newly selected element to the existing list. Here is the code. Please help.

This is index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function select_item(item,price)
{
if (item.length==0 || price.length==0 )
  { 
  document.getElementById("order").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("order").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","order.php?item="+item+"&price="+price,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<div id="order"></div>
</html>
<?php
echo "<a href=\"#\" onClick = \"select_item('Value1','Price1'); return false;\">Some Item1 here</a>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href=\"#\" onClick = \"select_item('Value2','Price2'); return false;\">Some Item2 here</a>";
?>
```

And this is order.php

```
<?php
$item=$_GET["item"];
echo "<form action=\"#\">";
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" checked=\"yes\" name=\"vehicle\" value=\"Bike\">$item<br>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might use this:

```
<form action ....
<div id="order"></div> 
</form>
```

and

```
document.getElementById("order").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

and order.php

```
<?php  
$item=$_GET["item"];  
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" checked=\"yes\" name=\"vehicle\" value=\"Bike\">$item<br>";  
?>
```